# How to insert "and" word in the functions and variables names?

Tags: naming-conventions, naming

I have a dictionary that holds `BusinessCategories` and the `cityId` :

is `businessCategoriesAndCities` a good name, or should I remove the 'and' word?

I also have a function that update the state of the old and the new categories. How should I name this function? `updateOldAndNewCategories` ?

Comment: I think including 'And' is good.  If you are working in an organization that has standards or conventions, you should follow them.  Otherwise, you can choose what you like best.  Verbose variable names make it much easier to understand the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dictionary has keys as `businessCategories` and values as `cityId`, preferred name would be `businessCategoriesToCities`. And if both are part of the key itself, `businessCategoriesAndCities` seems good.

As the function is updating both old as well as new categories, you should go with just `updateCategories`.

Comment: thank you for your response, but the dictionary have to keys the first one cityId, and the second one categoriesIds

Comment: Then `businessCategoriesAndCities` seems good.